# Xamarin.Forms - Debug.WriteLine() - where does the output go?

Tags: debugging, xamarin, output, xamarin.forms

I have a simple Xamarin.Forms project that I'm running in Visual Studio, using an iphone emulator. I have the following code in App.cs:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("---------- OnStart called!");
}
```

Where exactly is that supposed to output to? I don't see it in any of the Visual Studio output windows (Build, Build Order, Debug, Xamarin, Xamarin Diagnostics).

Comment: Perhaps it's changed now, but I see it in the "Debug" output window when debugging Xamarin Forms on Android

Answer (score 12):

Using `Console.WriteLine()` works with Device Log. Also you can filter out all device log with `mono-stdout` tag.

Comment: The name `Console` does not exist in the current context though.

Comment: Then just start `using System;`

Comment: Is it possible to use it's own Tag? How?

Answer (score 2):

Rider has a plugin called Logcat, when I write

```
Console.WriteLine("**** Hi mate");
```

, then I can filter the Logcat window for **** and it will show the Console.WriteLine's

This is in Xamarin Forms, for both iOS and Android

Answer (score 1):

It should be on the device log, for example on Android you can use the Android Device Monitor to see the message, You can always use `Console.Writeline()` to see those messages on the debug console.

Comment: Hmm, ok - what library do I need to include ("using xyz...") to use Console?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("True!");` I think is `using System;`

Comment: I thought so, but I have using System - but Console still is not recognized for some reason.

Comment: Are you using PCL or Shared project?

Comment: Oooh, then you must use Debug.WriteLine, and it will pop up inside Application Output.

Comment: I see - where is Application Output? That option does not show up in the list in the output window ("Show output from:") - only Build, Build Order, Debug, Xamarin, and Xamarin Diagnostics.

Comment: Debug is not showing anything? it should print 2 lines on the console.

Comment: Silly me, I figured it out - I was running the application without debug (Ctrl+F5) instead of with debug (F5). Doh!

Answer (score 1):

It will be coming in application output window. if it is not open automatically, you can go to view -> Pads -> Application Output. This was about mac visual studio. i am not sure about windows.