# Xamarin.Forms can't output to console to debug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, output

As in the title, I am trying to debug my program by writing to the console in xamarin forms. I have tried  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine and Console.WriteLine in multiple paces and **neither of them has any output that I can see in the debug output or the device log.**

Edit:

See no output in Visual Studio Debug output for the following code.

```
using CustomRenderer;
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CarpApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private static ILogger logger = DependencyService.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            logger.Trace("Test1");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test2");
        }

        private void OnMessagesTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Test3");
            Console.WriteLine("Test4");
            logger.Trace("Test5");
        }

        private void OnFindTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new MapPage());
        }

        private void OnGetRidTapped(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new GetRidPage());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Can you share sample of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms - Debug.WriteLine() - where does the output go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847530/xamarin-forms-debug-writeline-where-does-the-output-go)

Comment: Sorry for this trivial question, but do you run your app in **debug** and not in **release**? It only works in **debug**

Comment: yea it's running in debug but I feel like its probably something that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem, the issue was that there were a bunch of screwed up namings throughout the project.

Answer (score 1):

As as a workaround you can add NLog logging to your app (See [This link](https://martynnw.wordpress.com/2016/10/16/logging-with-nlog-in-xamarin-forms/) for details).
In addition to FileTarget logging, you can define a DebuggerTarget, which goes directly into the console.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't seem to have worked. I see no output to the console for the code I added to the original post. I am using Visual Studio and looking at the output from Debug.

Comment: I create the targets programatically:

#if DEBUG
   LoggingRule debugrule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);
   config.LoggingRules.Add(debugrule);
   LoggingRule rule2 = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, new DebuggerTarget());
   config.LoggingRules.Add(rule2);
#else
LoggingRule loggingrule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, fileTarget);
   config.LoggingRules.Add(loggingrule);
LogManager.Configuration = config;